# PostgreSQL SSPI authentication from different domain

Tags: postgresql, authentication, sspi

Help, please.
It is required to configure authentication of the client connection to the Postgres database using the SSPI protocol within the corporate network on MS Windows.

The network has a 3-level domain structure: **dep1.org.dn1**

Users logging in by OS as:
*user1@dep1*
or *dep1\user1*

How it is organized is not known for certain.
But there are successful examples.
Successful configuration:

postgresql.conf:

```
listen_addresses = '*'
```

pg_hba.conf:

```
host all all 11.0.0.0/8 sspi map=db1map include_realm=1
```

pg_ident.conf:

```
db1map user1@dep1
```

Moreover, the user can't pass with the following settings:

```
db1map user1@dep1.org.dn1
db1map dep1\user1
db1map dep1\user1@org.dn1
```

The problem is how to configure for a user from another domain **dep2.org.dn2**,
which is authorized in the OS as: *user2@dep2*

I tried the following cases, but they didn't work:

```
user2@dep2
db1map user2@dep1.org.dn2
db1map dep2\user2
db1map dep2\user2@org.dn2
```

Moreover, authentication through the database of this user using MD5 is successful:

pg_hba.conf:

```
host all user2 11.х.х.х/32 md5
```

Comment: Please format your configuration as code, or in some other way that makes it stand out and preserves line endings and whitespace.